# Number of elements of a set A

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f\colon [0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be continuous and such that $f(0)=f(1)$. Let $$A=\{\,(t,s)\in [0,1]\times [0,1], \;t\neq s,\;f(t)=f(s)\,\}$$

Then card$(A)$?

Can we think of function $g(s,t)=f(t)-f(s)$ which is continuous with $f(0,1)=f(1,0)=0$ then image of line joining $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is also zero. Or using $Z(g)={(s,t):g(s,t)=0}.$

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem):

1. If $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then $A=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, then $A$ is uncountably infinite.
2. Now assume $f(x_0) = c > 0$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$. Then $f$ takes every value $[0,c)$ on the interval $[0,x_0)$ and again on $(x_0,1]$. Hence $card(A) \geq card([0,c))$.

Regarding your idea: I think you can make it work with the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) assuming that $f$ is continuously differentiable with $f'(0) > 0$ or $f'(1) < 0$.